# Present change in cumulative sum of point in polygon by month

Tags: qgis, time

I have a data table that contains points in a city, and a polygon for statistical areas within the city. For each point, I have the date it first appeared, from 2009 to 2016.
I want to create in some way a map that presents the cumulative sum of points for each statistical area, by month. Ideally, it would show the growth of number of points for each area with color change.

edit:
I use QGIS 2.18. The database is exported from R to csv, and then imported to QGIS. The time format is dd/mm/yyyy though it won't be difficult to reformat it if necessary.

Comment: You need to add more information. Which Software or Database do you use ? Which format is the date ?

Comment: How do you want the map to display the data? Different maps for each month? Show the sum in the polygons? can you post an example of what exactly you want to make?

Comment: @HasanMustafa Ideally I want a sort of animation that goes through all the months and present the change in sum for each polygon. The relative level of sum should be represented with a graduated color. I've seen questions about a somewhat similar animation, but I find my data to be more complicated, as I need to generate a sum for each month and each polygon before animating the result